# What can be causing problems for some of my KML's not rendering from Fusion Tables?

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I have 3 KML's that do not draw at all and 2-3 that act sporadically depending on what zoom level they are at. I checked the file limitations and I don't seem to be violating any of the limits. I went back to my original shapefiles to check for geometry errors. One of the files had geometry errors and I fixed them yet it didn't seem to fix the problem of the KML not rendering. I've also implemented zoom functionality with Googles Visualization API and geoxml3 processor. Here are some interesting things that happen with my application:

1. One of the KML files that does not draw will actually respond to the
   zoom functionality by zooming to its extent but still won't draw the
   polygon; evidence that the KML is being parsed but not drawing.
2. One of the KML files that does not draw will eventually draw if I
   click on the polygon next to it and am zoomed in close enough. It
   will not initially.
3. I have two KML files that draw when zoomed out but 'disappear' when
   I zoom in.

My application is [here](https://github.com/danagerous/school-catchment) and my fusion table is [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1yc4wo1kBGNJwpDm6e-eJY_KL1YhQWfftjhA38w8). If anyone has had similar problems and was able to fix them I would really appreciate to know how it was accomplished because I'm stumped at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all: **Fusion Tables are still experimental**

some issues:

1. **`South Nelson Elementary`**  is missing in `varID`
2. **`JV Humphries Secondary`** `Polygons` needs to be fixed

Comment: Good point Dr.Molle; I sometimes forget it is still experimental. Thanks again for the second set of eyes and help.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post an update.

It turns out some of my data did have geometry errors; those were fixed and converted to KML.

The problem is my actual coding. The code was orginally written to simply display polygons from an array and to be turned on/off via a checkbox. The reason for this was to be able to view adjacent boundaries of the other polygons. I achieved this in my initial coding and the user had to zoom into the area of interest via Google's map functionality.

Then I was asked to have a zoom function when the checkbox was clicked to have the application zoom to the polygon in question. This of course works but it depends on which order the checkboxes are clicked on. I'm fairly certain it has to do with how the empty array is populated as checkboxes are clicked on/off.

I don't fully understand the logic of how the code decides which polygon to zoom or not zoom to. All I know is that if all checkboxes are unchecked then each checkbox is checked on/off one at a time the zoom functionality works.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to have each checkbox act 'independently' to zoom regardless of order clicked I would appreciate it.